# Update image position in notification as progress changes

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

below is my xml for notification custom layout for expandable and simple view

**Normal View (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znr5U.png)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Title and message body -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PickUp in 6 minutes"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:progressTint="@color/black"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="50" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_car1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_car3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Expandable View (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQdFA.png)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_5sdp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:text="PickUp in 6 minuts"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meet at the pickup point for the ride you have booked."
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:progressTint="@color/black"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_car2"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_car3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ride_custome_notification_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/car_photo" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberPlate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="GAK 7522"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carModel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Grey Toyota corola"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the image should be move when progress changes as like thumb in seekbar

Below is the that i've tried but Im unable to get required results proprely.

```
    fun notificationTest() {
        val channelId = "ride_driver_info"
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Ride Driver Info",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val remoteViews = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.ride_notification_custome_layout)

        val expandableContent =
            RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.ride_notification_expand_custome_layout)
        val sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            resources,
            R.drawable.profile
        ) // Replace with your image resource
        val roundedBitmap = getRoundedBitmap(sourceBitmap) // Adjust the radius as needed

        expandableContent.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.user_image, roundedBitmap)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo2)
//            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
            .setCustomBigContentView(expandableContent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true) // To make it non-dismissable
            .build()


        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)

        val maxProgress = 100
        var progress = 0
        while (progress < 100) {
            progress += 10

            remoteViews.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, maxProgress, progress, false)
            expandableContent.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar2, maxProgress, progress, false)

            val density = resources.displayMetrics.density // Get the screen density
            val progressInDp = (progress * (density+30))

            if (progressInDp > 1) {
                remoteViews.setViewLayoutMargin(R.id.iv_car1, MARGIN_START, progressInDp, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP)
                expandableContent.setViewLayoutMargin(R.id.iv_car2, MARGIN_START, progressInDp, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP)
                notificationManager.notify(1, notification)
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            }
        }
    }
```